# Group and add values in a vector/array in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, vector, text-parsing

I am a newbie in Java and have to do some manipulation on delimiter separated data being provided to me by someone else, from which I've already taken the desired fields and stored into an array of strings. It looks somewhat similar to following :

```
     String [] toseparate =null;
     Vector <String> myVector = new Vector<String>();
     myVector.add (a xyz 12 b efg 13 a pqr 45 c erer 18 a vbv 27 d tag 40 c etc 16....)
    //These values are derived from a separate array which I've parsed based on delimiters.
     toseparate = myVector.toArray(new String[myVector.size()]);
```

(and so on), this is an array of length in range of 50 indices and unsorted.
        The result should be like:

```
    a,84,b,13,c,34....
```

(that is sum of the digits corresponding to the string).Apart from that, the order of a,b,c... doesn't matter.
I think it can be done using multi-dimension array (2D) as well and will change the approach according to expert advices. 
Please help me regarding it.
Thank you so much.

Comment: What specifically are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I am not able to figure out what approach to use and to get these values.

Comment: Consider using a `HashMap<String,Integer>`.

Comment: Start looking into Maps (HashMap, etc). Specifically, I would consider using HashMap<String, Integer>

Comment: Dear  @DavidWallace, it's just a portion of what I want to do finally, but will show soon after some adjustments.

Comment: thanks  @Jason, trying HashMap, will update.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the split() function to parse out your delimited string? Take a look at:
http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs302/examples/Parsing/parseString.html

Regardless of how you parse, it looks like all your data is in triplets where only the first and last values matter:

```
a xyz 12 b efg 13 a pqr 45 c erer 18 a vbv 27 d tag 40 c etc...
```

resolves to:

```
a 12 b 13 a 45 c 18 a 27 d 40 ...
```

Assuming that, you could loop over the array in threes and accumulate the values as you go. In pseudocode:

```
for( i = 0; i < array.length(); i+=3) {
    if(!map.containsKey( array[i] )) map.put( array[i], array[i+2] );
    else map.put( array[i], map.get( array[i] ) + array[i+2] );
}
```

For the map, you could use a Hashmap<String,int>, I suppose.

Comment: I've already obtained these values after splitting from a really long string and the data is actually in group of 5 (and can vary according to new requirements), I've shown triplet for the sake of simplicity. I am already using loop, but I was looking for some more efficient method if it was in java.

Comment: Is there a different delimiter between the 5 values and each set of 5? If so, there may be a more efficient way.

Comment: I've got these values from a string having delimiters using split(regex), if there's an efficient way, can it be done ?

Comment: If there are two different delimiters, you can split all the groups and then split the values as you loop through the groups. You can add your values using the hashmap at the same time if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, Integer> totals = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for(int i = 0 ; i < myVector.size(); i += 3) {
    Integer total = totals.get(myVector.get(i));
    if(total == null) {
        total = 0;
    }
    total += Integer.parseInt(myVector.get(i + 2));
    totals.put(myVector.get(i), total);
}
```